# Kendo UI Grid Number of Columns Limits

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to create a KENDO UI GRID with 2000 columns. At 433 the grind stops workings. As you can see in the DEMO, if you remove ANY of the columns the grid works, if you add 1 column it just stops working.

Here you can see the DEMO.  To test just remove 1 field from the Columns array and the results appear.

For me it stops working at 433 columns.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  selectable: "multiple cell",
  allowCopy: true,
  columns: [
    { field: "developerName", width: "200px" },
    { field: "project", width: "200px" },
    { field: "J1A17", width: "70px" },
    { field: "J2A17", width: "70px" },
    { field: "J3A17", width: "70px" },
    { field: "J4A17", width: "70px" },
    { field: "J5A17", width: "70px" },
    { field: "J6A17", width: "70px" },
    { field: "J7A17", width: "70px" },
    { field: "J8A17", width: "70px" },
    { field: "J9A17", width: "70px" },
    { field: "J10A17", width: "70px" },
    { field: "J11A17", width: "70px" },
    { field: "J12A17", width: "70px" },
    ....
```

**[DEMO OF THE GRID NOT WORKING WITH 433](https://codepen.io/igcorreia/pen/Rjwxpw?editors=1010)**

Comment: Assuming this works, and you have 433 columns, don't you end up with a page tens of thousands of pixels wide?

Comment: I tried to run 434 columns, it works fine though this test i ran on mac..

While there are no limitations for the number of columns in a Kendo UI Grid, some browsers and computer configurations might not be able to handle such big amount of data.

Comment: I see. I was just making a prototype with 2 years in columns, the amount I need is more than 600 and I didn't wanted to use other widget.